# Check if a string includes any of the keys in a hash and return the value of the key it contains

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I have a hash with multiple keys and a string which contains either none or one of the keys in the hash.

```
h = {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"v2", "k3"=>"v3"}
s = "this is an example string that might occur with a key somewhere in the string k1(with special characters like (^&*$#@!^&&*))"
```

What would be the best way to check if `s` contains any of the keys in `h` and if it does, return the value of the key that it contains?

For instance, for the above examples of `h` and `s`, the output should be `v1`.

*Edit: Only the string would be user defined. The hash will always be the same.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find this way readable:

```
hash_key_in_s = s[Regexp.union(h.keys)]
p h[hash_key_in_s] #=> "v1"
```

Or in one line:

```
p h.fetch s[Regexp.union(h.keys)] #=> "v1"
```

And here is a version not using regexp:

```
p h.fetch( h.keys.find{|key|s[key]} ) #=> "v1"
```

Comment: I somehow missed your answer earlier. Excellent!

Answer (score 3):

create a regex out of Hash `h` keys and `match` in string:

```
h[s.match(/#{h.keys.join('|')}/).to_s]
# => "v1"
```

Or as Amadan suggested using [Regexp#escape](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) for safety:

```
h[s.match(/#{h.keys.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join('|')}/).to_s]
# => "v1"
```

If String `s` was evenly spaced, we could have done something like this too:

```
s =  "this is an example string that might occur with a key somewhere in the string k1 (with special characters like (^&*$\#@!^&&*))"
h[(s.split & h.keys).first]
# => "v1"
```

Comment: `h.keys.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join('|')` for safety unless keys are, in fact, regexps.

Comment: You should first get `key`, then obtain `h[key]` if `key` is not `nil`, in case the string does not contain any of the hash's keys. Rather than using `join` (which is fine), you could do the first step like so: `key = s[Regexp.union(h.keys.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)))]
 => "k1"`. One more thing: nice answer!

Comment: Thanks Cary for your valued suggestions as always :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Amadan and apologies for not noting this earlier but `escape` is not needed in this case since only string is user defined. Also @shivam, you can change third option to `h[(s.split(/[\s(]/) & h.keys).first]` so it works for the example string.